# css sticky footer in an asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I am trying to create a footer that sticks to the bottom of the page.  I have:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="content">
            <uc2:logo ID="logo1" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <uc1:footer ID="footer1" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Here is my css

```
body {
    margin: 30px 10px 0px 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font: 76% Arial,Verdana,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}
html, body, form, #wrap { height: 100%; }
form > #wrap { height: auto; min-height: 100%; }

#wrap {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;

}

#content {

    text-align:left;

}


#footer {
 clear: both;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 10;
 width:1000px;
 margin:auto;
}
```

What am I missing?  The footer appears below the viewport (scrollbars are also on the page).  I'm expecting it to be some type of margin issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at this: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

Comment: Had to add the form element to the css rule about the body and html element and then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try position absolute :

```
#footer {
 clear: both;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 10;
 width:1000px;
 margin:auto;
 bottom:0px;
 height:50px;
}
```

Comment: yeah - position: absolute; was also in the solution.  thanks!