# HTML/CSS issues

Tags: css, html

I have a site that has the following structure:

```
<div id="page_wrapper">
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content-wrapper"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Now I have set html, body and page_wrapper to 100% in CSS.  The goal here is to get the footer to be at either the bottom of the content or the bottom of the window -- whichever is visually lower.  I've read a lot of things about how to do it, but I can't seem to get it to work correctly.

```
html, body, #page_wrapper { height: 100%; }

#page_wrapper {
width: 864px;
margin: 0 auto;
min-height: 100%;
background: url('path/to/image') repeat-y;
}

#content-wrapper {
position: relative;
width: 824px;
min-height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
#footer, #header {width: 824px; margin: 0 auto; }
#footer {
border-top: 4px solid #000;
position: relative;
margin-top: -7.5em;
}
```

It sorta seems to work.  But problem I am seeing is, that if I zoom out my page_wrapper seems to almost reset its height to 100% but as I zoom in, it gets shorter and shorter and shorter causing overlap in the footer and content text instead of pushing the footer down.

Any idea how to repair something like that?  I'm at my wits end with it trying to google up an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated my answer with a test html, works quite fine in chrome 13. I tried zooming in and out and the footer stays put.**

You should put your footer outside of the page-wrapper. Then give it a negative margin equal to the height of the footer. You can change the height of either the header or the content-wrapper to see the footer stick to the bottom of the page-wrapper instead of the browser window. If you open the html as is you will see the blue footer sticking to the bottom of the page and the page-wrapper taking up 100% of the window.

Please note that this is broken without a fix in Firefox 4 and 5. Also it doesnt work in IE 5.5 and earlier.

To make this work properly in IE6 add height: 100%; to #page_wrapper

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    body, html {height: 100%;margin:0;padding:0;}
    #page_wrapper {min-height: 100%; background-color: red;}
    #header{height: 200px; background-color: green;}
    #content-wrapper{height: 200px; background-color: yellow;}
    #footer {height: 7.5em;margin-top: -7.5em; background-color: blue; position:relative;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="page_wrapper">
      <div id="header"></div>
      <div id="content-wrapper"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
  </body>
<html>
```

live example of this can be found on:

https://www.effacts.com/effacts/public?context=107

a proper sheet and html can be found here:

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Comment: I've tried that too Benjamin.  and that just aligns #footer to the bottom of #content-wrapper in the looks of live HTML..  but the #page_wrapper seems to go 100% of the page but the footer isn't aligned to the bottom of it...

Comment: go checkout the stickyfooter page I added :> and please note that this is broken in firefox 4+ as far as I know. I used the above example for the effacts site I linked a while back and as far as I know it works quite good except for a few new and really old browser versions.

Comment: Yeah I found stickyfooter somewhere, that actually somewhat worked for me and I used it as a base to get the full working code for mine.  So thanks for that, much appreciated.  It works in the newest FF out and IE9.  Old browsers I don't really care about -- let them upgrade.

Very minor overlap when I zoom in, but I use the 'zoom in' as an estimate of lower resolution.  Seems like my push div doesn't like to work when it's zoomed in too far otherwise it's perfect.

Comment: Maybe you are combining % size with px/em/border size on the same element? you should always have either of em on a element and never both.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help:

[css sticky footer in an asp.net page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114669/css-sticky-footer-in-an-asp-net-page)

absolute position the footer div...

Answer (score 1):

In #footer css try adding clear:both;

or

add in footer CSS right after position: relative; bottom:5px;

With position: relative you can actually use, top, right, bottom and left.

If you always want it at bottom you can put in as bottom:5px; If you want it at the bottom center then you can put in bottom: 5px; and right or left ...

5px above is just an example you can change pixel to as many as you want.

Furthermore, you can also have clear:both with it there as that clear make sure there is no other content that would override it.

Comment: I just tried that, and it didnt work.  That puts it directly after my content instead of being aligned to the bottom of the page is the content is too short to fill the page.

Comment: add in footer CSS right after position: relative;    bottom:5px;