# Add Footer to the HTML Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I'm generating some XML data in an application to render the HTML page. This works fine, the page displays OK. But then I tried to add footer. The footer should be displayed at the bottom of the page but mine doesn't. Please help..

```
<footer>
    <div style="vertical-align:bottom;font-size:10px;">
      <div style="color:gray; text-align:left;">
        <b>ABC Company</b>
        Address :
        Ph:
      </div>          
    </div>
  </footer>
```

[image]
**Code**

[image]

Comment: This have any associated css (other than the stuff in the tag)? Anyhow, there seems to be an answer in this related q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114669/css-sticky-footer-in-an-asp-net-page?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of the screenshot, the height of the page is bigger than footer.

Have you hard coded in height values for items above it?

That would be my guess without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've submitted, it looks like perhaps the `GetValuesFromXML()` function has not been called.

Can you show where `FOOTER` is declared?
Is it initialized properly by calling `GetValuesFromXML()` prior to being used in the prior method?

Comment: it is declared outside of the method. private string FOOTER = string.Empty;

Comment: So, then, you're sure that your `GetValuesFromXML()` method is being called?